# MVC javascript from controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've seen other posts on this but I can't get it to work.  I've tried a million different ways.  All I want to do is fire some javascript dynamically generated from a controller based on an input textbox and a button click using the default mobile template. I'm sure I'm doing it wrong.  The furthest I can get is to have the javascript show up on the page but not execute.

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection Form)
    {
        string injectedJS = "";
        if (! String.IsNullOrEmpty(Form["searchstring"]))
        {
           //create js
            ViewBag.injectedJS = //<created js>
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Shared view

```
@RenderSection("jsheader", required: false)
```

View

```
@section jsheader{
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).bind("pageinit", function () {
         @ViewBag.injectedJS;  
     });      
 </script>
                 }

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "mycontroller", FormMethod.Post))
{
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li data-role="list-divider"></li>
    <li>             
             <input type="text" name="searchstring" id="searchbox" />
    </li>
</ul>

<input type="submit" id="searchbutton" autofocus="autofocus" value="Submit"                
}
```

Comment: Please show us the actual HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

Razor views automatically encode any data that you output.

You need to call `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.injectedJS)` to prevent it from HTML-encoding the Javascript.

Comment: Good call, but how do I get the javascript to execute?  It just gets put back into the page without executing

Comment: not sure how to post html,  but I can see the js injected in firebug under the script tag after I click the button.  However, the html tab still shows the initially loaded script